# the Error : The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python code assignment in which I have to fill some of its parts.
I have to create and define the given functions, and this is what I have wrote :

```
import numpy as np

# define candidate functions
# you can use numpy functions
def h1(s):
    return (-min(1,s))

def h2(s):
    return (0.5*s + 0.5)

def h3(s):
    return (min(s, 0.2*s))

def h4(s):
    if s >= 0 :
     return (min(s, 0.2*s))
    else:
     return (max(s,0.2*s))
```

then I had to run the below code :

```
# compute the values of functions

s_arr = np.arange(-8,8.01,0.01)
h1_arr = h1(s_arr)
h2_arr = h2(s_arr)
h3_arr = h3(s_arr)
h4_arr = h4(s_arr)
```

which gives this error :

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: I think you need to explain what you're trying to achieve. You can't pass a numpy array to the Python built-in *min()* function in that way. Maybe you're looking for the minimum value in the array in which case, as an example, your *h1()* function could be implemented as *return -min(1, s.min())*

Comment: Where exactly? Please post the full error trace - see how to create a [mre]

Comment: you are getting this error because you are trying to find minimum in your function between an arrays or array and value, so python cannot decide which value to pick from array, so you gotta be more clear

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are your functions meant to handle lists/arrays or just single numbers? If you're trying to iterate through the `s_arr` array (i.e. find `h1(s)`, `h2(s)`, etc. for every `s` in `s_arr`), you need to use a `for` loop for everything that's not vectorised (e.g. `h2` is vectorised, so no `for` loop needed there, but the default Python `min` function you're using is not vectorised, so you either need to use a `for` loop or replace it with the vectorised `np.amin` or something similar.

Comment: That `if s >= 0 :` line does not work with an array `s`.  What do you intend to happen here?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with *h1* function.

It looks that you attempt **for each its element** do the following:

- compute minimum of this element and *1*,
- return this value with the sign changed.

And return an array composed of these results.

To do it in *Numpy*, you can define *h1* function as:

```
def h1(s):
    return -np.where(s < 1, s, 1)
```

This function operates the following way:

- `s < 1` - compute the selection condition - whether the current
  element is less than *1*,
- if yes, take this element (*s*),
- otherwise take *1*,
- return the value found so far with changed sign,
- the final result is an array composed of result of the above
  computation for each element.

Your second function is OK, but you can define it without parentheses:

```
def h2(s):
    return 0.5*s + 0.5
```

Your *h3* function can be defined as:

```
def h3(s):
    wrk = s * 0.2
    return np.where(wrk < s, wrk, s)
```

But a faster implementation is based on the fact that:

- `s * 0.2` is less than just `s` for positive values,
- for *0* there is no difference (you can return each of the above formulas),
- for negative values `s * 0.2` is greater than just `s`.

So you can define this function also as:

```
def h3(s):
    return np.where(s > 0, s * 0.2, s)
```

And to cope with *h4* case, first define an auxiliary function:

```
def h4fun(s):
    if s >= 0:
        return min(s, 0.2*s)
    else:
        return max(s, 0.2*s)
```

Then define *f4* as:

```
def h4(s):
    return np.array(list(map(h4fun, s)))
```